# Which probability formula do I use to solve the question?

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

An oil prospector will drill a succession of holes in a given area to find a productive well. The probability he is successful on a given trial is 0.2.

1. What is the probability that the tenth hole drilled yields the fourth productive well?
2. If ten holes are drilled, what is the probability of exactly 4 productive wells?

I am having trouble deciding what should be done on each question. I am fairly confident that I should do

$10 \choose 4$$0.2^4(1-0.2)^6$

but I am not sure which one to do it on. I think I need to use that formula to find the probability of exactly 4 wells, but then how do I solve the first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression applies to the 2nd question.

For the 1st question, you have the more restrictive situation where there were exactly 3 successes in the 1st 9 trials and a success on the 10th trial:

$\left[\binom{9}{3} \times (0.2)^3 \times (0.8)^6\right] \times (0.2).$